# Plugin for wordpress woocommerce filter navigation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with filtering by multiple attributes.
I use default Woocommerce Layered Navigation widget.

I have 3 attributes:

Length (Floor, Short)
Fabrics (Silk, Satin, Cotton)
Color (Mint, Black, Milk, Red...)

I expect that if I choose, for example, red, black and short attributes I will see only short dress red or black color.

But there is no way to select in settings OR query for the same attributes and AND query between different attributes. I can select only "red AND black AND short" logic or "red OR black OR short" logic. But I need "(red OR black) AND short" logic, because red and black is the same attribute.

Is there any plugin that will work in this way?